# error in float variable-c

Tags: c, variables, floating-point

friends i am a computer science student and my lecturer given me a assignment to write a program to input 20 numbers into array and count the total and average of the marks.so i have written the above code as answer.now when i check the answers with inputs there is a small error in average.if the correct average is 48.59,the program gives average as 48.00.i tried to solve the problem and i was unable to do it.can someone help me?

im using CODEBLOCKs to write programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int grades[20];
   int a,b,c,d,tot=0,high=0;
   float avg=0;
   for(a=0;a<20;a++)
    {
        printf("Input the Mark : ");
        scanf("%d",&d);

        if(d>=0&&d<=100)
            grades[a]=d;
        else
    {
            printf("OUT OF RANGE.PLEASE INPUT A VALID NUMBER.\n");
            a--;
    }
}
for(b=0;b<20;b++)
{
    tot=tot+grades[b];
}

avg=tot/20;

high=grades[0];
for(c=0;c<20;c++)
{
    if(high<grades[c])
        high=grades[c];
}
printf("The Total Value is : %d\nThe Average is : %.02f\nHighest Value is : %d",tot,avg,high);
```

}

Answer (score 7):

The following uses integer division (even though you store the result in a floating-point variable):

```
avg=tot/20;
```

To force floating-point division, use:

```
avg=tot/20.0;
```

Comment: or if you have a variable int x instead (for a variable input, for example) use avg=tot/(float) x;

Comment: Or, for a more general solution, force the calculation to use a float value by using a float variable: `float divisor = 20.0f; avg=tot/divisor;`

Comment: According to a little program I have had to juggle with compiler bugs to compile, the nearest float to 16777217 / 20 is 8.388608125e+05 but `float f = 16777217 / 20.0;` sets f to 8.388608750e+05. Requires a compiler that defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 0 and does not (incorrectly) factor `(float)(s / 20.0)` and `s / 20.0f` as common sub-expressions. I ought to report this compiler bug now.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Awesome. Thanks ever so much for going through the trouble of coming up with this example (and for the earlier two-word answer). Season's greetings!

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That example is not caused by double rounding in the `double` version. It is caused by rounding 16777217 to `float` in the `float` version. I think that, for division by 20, there is no case where `(float) (x/20.)` differs from `x/20.f`, given that `x` is a `float` (IEEE-754 32-bit binary).

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, for 20 or any other value exactly representable as a `float`, Figueroa's thesis applies. I will now delete my comments in shame (but still check whether GCC knew what it was doing when it compiled my loop to an infinite loop).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: There is no shame; humans make mistakes when doing hard stuff. Those who do not make mistakes are not trying hard enough.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Just a quick note to echo what Eric said, and to thank both of you for taking the time to look this. It's been quite an informative thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
avg=tot/20;
```

The problem here is that tot and 20 are integers. The arithmetic division of tot/20 will
produce another integer, not a floating point number. The result will be promoted to
floating point before being assigned to the float variable avg, but the decimal fraction
does not exist, because of the integer division.

*The solution is very simple.*

```
avg = tot/20.0
```

By adding a decimal fraction to the divisor, that is changing 20 to 20.0, the division is
promoted to floating point division, rather than integer division, because one of the
operands is a floating point number (20.0).

Alternatively, you could cast one of the integers as a floating point.

```
avg = (float)tot/20
```

What that does is to convert the integer tot into a floating point number before the
division takes place, having the same effect as appending a decimal fraction to the other
operand.

Also, in this printf format specifier for the floating point value "%.02f", the leading zero
is unnecessary. A specifier of "%.2f" is more correct. However, this has no effect on the
output.

I hope it helps! Have a great day!